# Textmate: change makeindex

Tags: nomenclature, textmate

To get the `nomencl` package working I need to run a `makeindex` line like:

```
makeindex <ﬁlename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <ﬁlename>.nls
```

I'm using Textmate, which has a built-in "Run Makeindex" button. I've tried this over and over again, but the nomenclature does not appear. A `.nlo` file is created though.

I'm not experienced with `makeindex`, so I was hoping to get some help here. Is it possible to change the "Run Makeindex" of Textmate such that the correct `makeindex` line (see above) is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to use the Terminal. From the Bundles menu choose Shell Script and the submenu "Open Terminal"; the shortcut <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> is available.

A Terminal window will open and there you can issue the command

```
makeindex <filename>.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o <filename>.nls
```

where in place of `<filename>` you write the name of your main file. Just hit "RETURN" and wait for the command to complete.

Defining new commands for TextMate menus requires knowing Python and Ruby, I'm afraid.